# How to include if-statement with decision variables in cplex which have summation function

Tags: optimization, cplex, opl

How can i convert If statement in constraint part which have decision variable. The costvship is the variable cost of shipment which needs to be included only when sum(m in M)x[m][n]*h[p][n]*weight[m] is greater than threshold Weight. Here x[m][n] and h[p][n] are binary variables.

```
 forall(p in P, n in N){costship[p][n] == costfship*z[p][n] + costvship*(sum(m in M)(x[m][n]*h[m][p]*weight[m])- Weight);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You may use a logical constraint to add an additional cost if a constraint is true.

Let me change the [zoo example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-66940178db6) to show that:

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

int penalty=1000;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30  + (nbBus40+nbBus30<=8)*penalty;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
}
```

that you can also write with sum

```
int nbKids=300;

{int} sizes={40,30};
float costBus[sizes]=[500,400];


int penalty=1000;
 
dvar int+ nbBus[sizes];

 
minimize
  sum(s in sizes)costBus[s]*nbBus[s] + (sum(s in sizes) nbBus[s]<=8)*penalty;
 
subject to
{
 sum(s in sizes)s*nbBus[s]>=nbKids;
}
```

Comment: Sir in my question I have to use if statement which is having terms from the decision variable that to in multiplication  `if {sum (m in M)x[m][n]*h[p][n]*weight[m] > Weight then take cvship into consideration`   how to write this in CPLEX  where x[m][n] is decision variable